# Compare two arrays and their elements against one another

Tags: python, arrays

How do i covert this into a Python code. I dont get how to do the compare between players and the winNum. The players is a 2D array and winNum is a 1D array.

below is a sample data set that i have been using

in the function what im trying to achive is that for every player in players i want to compare all their numbers with the winNum numbers and find if they match and if they do match i want to make 1 increment to the count. Both arrays have 8 elements and they are sorted from 0-6 and 6-8.

```
winNum = [0, 5, 20, 22, 23, 25, 0, 26]
player = [[0, 5, 20, 22, 23, 25, 0, 26],[14, 15, 21, 25, 26, 29, 30, 30],[3, 6, 8, 16, 25, 30, 0, 13]]
```

```
for i in  range (len(player)):
    for j in range(6):
            x = player[i][j]
            and compare with winNum[](0-6)
            if x is in winNum:
                count +=c1
                and move on to the next number
            else
                ignore and move on to the next number
```

Comment: Do you want to match each number of each player with winNum and increase the count only if ALL of them match, or just for one element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following code:

```
count=0
for i in range(len(player)):
    for j in range(8):
        x = player[i][j]
        if x in winNum:
            count+=1
```

You could also store the 'count' further by appending it to a new empty list. I wasn't sure if you wanted that too, but doing that is also straight forward.

```
count_list = []
for i in range(len(player)):
    count=0
    for j in range(8):
        x = player[i][j]
        if x in winNum:
            count+=1
    count_list.append(count)
```

Comment: after running the `player [1][numbers]` how do I get it to return the count before moving on to the next `player[2][numbers]`

Comment: Did you mean you want to store the count for one player set and then move to the next player set? I added some code in the solution.